# MYSQL LEFT JOIN BRINGS WRONG RESULTS

Tags: mysql, left-join

I am trying to figure out why the join brings back the results it does.

Here is a simple test im working on.

I have two tables : Table1 and Table2.

table1

```
-------------------
id    name      amount
---------------------
1   | Fred      | 2
3   | Fred      | 3
5   | Fred      | 4
2   | Hellen    | 3
4   | Hellen    | 3
6   | Hellen    | 3
```

table2

```
-------------------
id    name      amount
---------------------
1   | Fred      |4
2   | Hellen    |3
3   | Paul      |3
4   | Fridah    |5
```

When i use the following statement

```
SELECT p.name,sum(p.amount) as amount FROM `table1` as p  
left join table2 as c on p.name = c.name GROUP BY c.name , p.name
```

I get this result

```
---------------
name    amount
---------------     
Fridah  | 5
Paul    | 3
Fred    | 12
Hellen  | 9
```

But this is really wierd. I want the sum of `amount` from just table1, b ut the join gives me a sum of both tables. Why is this?

Comment: Can you set up a SQL Fiddle?  I don't believe that that query returns those results with that input data.

Answer (score 1):

Change the `group by` clause and include only `p.name` like `GROUP BY p.name` as below. See a demo fiddle here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6c0e3/1

```
SELECT p.name,sum(p.amount) as amount 
FROM `table1` as p  
left join table2 as c on p.name = c.name 
GROUP BY p.name
```

Results in

```
NAME    AMOUNT
Fred    9
Hellen  9
```

**EDIT:**

You can calculate the sum individually and then join the derived tables in order to get the correct sum amount from both tables as below. See update fiddle [Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6c0e3/23)

```
select X.name,X.amount,Y.amount2
from
(
select name,sum(amount) as amount
from table1
group by name
) X
left join
(
select name,sum(amount) as amount2
from table2
group by name
) Y on X.name = Y.name
```

Results In:

```
NAME    AMOUNT  AMOUNT2
Fred    9   4
Hellen  9   3
```

Comment: I have run into a problem. Have a look this http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6c0e3/7/0  Now id i try to get data from the second table I run into the same problem, the wrong results. How can I get correct results that sums both individual `amount` columns

Comment: Thank you for your help. To get the correct results from the second table's column, i added distinct to the column being summed. here is the fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6c0e3/12/0

Comment: @VictorNjoroge, See edited answer to get correct sum(amount) from both table.

Answer (score 1):

This is your query:

```
SELECT p.name, sum(p.amount) as amount
FROM `table1` as p left join
     table2 as c
     on p.name = c.name
GROUP BY c.name , p.name;
```

Your results suggest that the query you are running is:

```
SELECT p.name, sum(c.amount) as amount
-------------------^
FROM `table1` as p left join
     table2 as c
     on p.name = c.name
GROUP BY c.name , p.name;
```

If you run the correct query, you will get the results you expect.

EDIT:

The correct query would look like:

```
SELECT c.name, sum(p.amount) as amount
FROM table2 as c left join
     table1 as p
     on p.name = c.name
GROUP BY c.name;
```

Comment: I can see, but even still it would give me wrong results. have a look at this  sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6c0e3/7/0 and see what i mean. The query does not give the individual results.

Answer (score -1):

I have found an answer.
By adding distinct to the columns being summed, i was able to get the correct results.
have a look http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6c0e3/12/0

Thank you all for your help.

Comment: Sounds good that you have found the solution yourself but are you sure the solution you opted for gives you corect result? I don't think so cause `sum(amount)` for `helen` in table1 is 3 whereas it should be 9. Just though of letting you know.